# Fragment Animation (Enter/Exit transition) in Navigation Component with Bottom Navigation View reloads when Tabs switched

Tags: bottomnavigationview, android-architecture-navigation, android-jetpack-navigation, fragment-transitions, android-navhostfragment

I have a Bottom Navigation View with 5 Tabs and each tab has its own NavGraph. Lets assume I'm navigation with Tab1 through Fragment1 -> Fragment2 -> Fragment3

There is custom enter/exit transitions to each route (i.e. from Fragment1 -> Fragment2 -> Fragment3). Now I'm on Fragment3 and tap on Tab2 of Bottom Navigation View, it opens it own Graph of fragments flow => FragmentX -> FragmentY -> FragmentZ

Issue occurred when I tap on Tab1 again, the latest loaded Fragment3 in this TAB1 graph reloads its Enter transition.

Here is visual representation of scenario: [Navigation Component + Bottom navigation view + Custom enter exit fragments transitions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O36Uq.png)

I've tried multiple solutions, kindly get me out of this trouble.